# push cache to insecure registry by buildx

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-buildkit

How to push cache to an insecure registry? I have already added it to my docker config and can log in successfully by `docker login`.
This is my docker command:

```
docker buildx build --cache-to=type=registry,ref=my-insecure-repo/lib/test:0730 \
    --output=type=image,push=true \
    -t test:0730 -f ut.dockerfile .
```

and get error msg:

```
#12 ERROR: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
------
 > exporting to image:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I tried to add `--output=type=image,push=true,registry.insecure=true` but same error. Also tried add `--allow security.insecure` but get: `failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = granting entitlement security.insecure is not allowed by build daemon configuration`

Docker version: Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Is the registry using an untrusted tls key, or http without any tls configuration?

Comment: @BMitch http without any tls configuration

Answer (score 2):

The [current advice for buildkit](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41059#issue-629626784) is to configure your insecure registries in the docker engine with the http scheme prefixed:

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "insecure-registries" : [ "http://my-insecure-repo" ]
}
```

Make sure to reload the docker engine after adjusting this file (`systemctl reload docker`).

However buildx calls buildkit directly so the above probably won't work for this question. Instead you'll want to pass a [config file](https://github.com/docker/buildx#--config-file) with `http: true`. See [this comment](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/94#issuecomment-534831828) for more details.

Comment: I tried to pass a config file to set my insecure registry but couldn't figure out how to do it.  I assume that `--config` is passed to `docker buildx create`, but I don't know what to put into the config file. It would be great if your answer spelled this out explicitly.  The github link you provided for config file doesn't seem to point to relevant information.  Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: `docker buildx bake --set=*.output=type=registry,registry.insecure=true` in addition to the config above works for me

Comment: `docker buildx build . -t localhost/docker/some:latest --output=type=registry,registry.insecure=true` without without bake

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links are helpful:

- https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#run---networknonehostdefault
- https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#run---securityinsecuresandbox

From what I understood it should be possible to provide them on builder-creation with the `--buildkitd-flags` flag (`docker buildx create --help`)